# PatchEntity ignore data from an ajax request in Cakephp 3.0

Tags: php, cakephp, orm, entity, cakephp-3.0

I often use the `patchEntity` function to hydrate my entity with form data, and it works fine, even with an ajax request.

But when I tried to insert data from an an ajax request with JSON data, patchEntity failed to retrieve the data.

My ajax request is very simple:

```
var rate = function (user, rate, success, error) {
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: baseUrl + 'rate/add',
            data: {
                id: this.id,
                user: user.id
                rate: rate
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: success,
            error: error
        });
});
```

In my Rate controller, my add function looks like:

```
 public function add()
 {
     if ($this->request->isAjax()) {
        $this->layout = 'ajax';
        $rate = $this->Rate->newEntity();
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $rate = $this->Rate->patchEntity($rate, $this->request->data);
           if ($rate->errors()) {
                $this->set([
                    'status' => 500,
                    'message' => $rate->errors()
                ]);
            } else {
                if ($this->rate->save($rate)) {
                    $this->set([
                        'status' => 200
                    ]);
                } else {
                    $this->set([
                        'status' => 500,
                        'message' => $rate->errors()
                    ]);
                }
            }
            return $this->render('/Ajax/result');
        }
}
```

This throw an exception:

> Cannot insert row, some of the primary key values are missing. Got (,
>   , ), expecting (id, user)

I can save my data using this instead of `$this->Rate->patchEntity($rate, $this->request->data);`

```
$rate['id'] = $this->request->data['id'];
$rate['user'] = $this->request->data['user'];
$rate['rate'] = $this->request->data['rate'];
```

**What sort of array do I have to pass to `patchEntity` function to makes this works?**

Comment: Please show your `Rate` entity code. Also, whenever you receive erros, please post the _exact_ error message and also include the related stacktrace!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to ndm's comment, I've checked the Rate Entity and just removed this part which was automatically generated by bake:

```
protected $_accessible = [
    'rate' => true,
];
```